# How to draw a customized shadow under the line on canvas in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a android app, and I try to draw some shadow under the line on canvas. How can I manage to do that.

I've draw some line with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), and setShadowLayer to renderPaint, so what I got is:
[image]
All point in shadow share the same offset to the red line.

But what I want is :
[image]
All shadow point lies under the gradient color line.

How can I achieve that, any prompt or work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I figure out that android did not support drawing shadow that like the second picture.

And, my bad, I can simply draw another blank line to be the shadow.